# UWP: How to add a button inside the bottom of an ellipse

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I want to have something like shown in this screenshot here: [image]

The Edit part should be in the bottom of the circle and should be tappable. How can I achieve this in UWP xaml?

Comment: Do you can to tap the circle too?

Comment: No, only the bottom part (highlighted in different color and with text Edit) should be tappable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just "draw over" a `Button` to the `Ellipse` in a layout control eg. in a `Grid`. Something like this:

```
 <Grid Height="100" Width="100" Background="Aqua">
     <Ellipse Fill="Red"/>
     <Button Background="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Edit" Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: So, I should have mentioned it in my post, but the background color of the button and the Grid can be different.

Comment: Of course, you can declare different values to the Grid and to the Button.

Comment: This is exactly how i'd do it.